# issue branching on small MIPS Assembly program

Tags: assembly, mips

My code needs to branch to a different label if the next number in an array if the next number is < current number * 2. I get a weird error where the console loops 0's until it crashes when I use the line `blt $t2, $t3, false` However it works just fine when I use `bne $t2, $t3, false` Of course I don't want to Branch if not equal I want to branch if less than. Below is the full code, I'll be grateful for any help.

```
    .data
A:      .word   2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 365
newline: .asciiz "\n"
true_message: .asciiz "true"
false_message: .asciiz "false"

    .text

main:
    # Initialize registers
    la $a0, A     # Load the address of the array A
    lw $t0, 0($a0)  # Load the first value into $t0
    addi $t1, $a0, 4  # Calculate the address of the next element

loop:
    lw $t2, 0($t1)   # Load the current element into $t2
    mul $t3, $t0, 2   # Double the previous element

    li $v0, 1       
    la $a0, ($t2)       
    syscall

    li $v0, 4      
    la $a0, newline      
    syscall

    li $v0, 1    
    la $a0, ($t3)     
    syscall

    li $v0, 4    
    la $a0, newline   
    syscall

    blt $t2, $t3, false   # If current element is not at least twice the previous, jump to false
    addi $t0, $t2, 0   # Update $t0 with the current element
    addi $t1, $t1, 4   # Move to the next element
    bnez $t1, loop   # If not at the end of the array, repeat the loop

true:
    li $v0, 4   # Print "true" message
    la $a0, true_message
    syscall
    j exit

false:
    li $v0, 4   # Print "false" message
    la $a0, false_message
    syscall
    j exit

exit:
    li $v0, 10  # Exit the program
    syscall
```

If there is a problem with the parameters or if something besides the area I mentioned is causing the trouble a comment would be appreciated.

Comment: You are expecting the pointer in $t1 to become zero somehow?  Pointers don't suddenly become zero from adding 4 to get to the next word. It's going to go 0x10010000, 0x10010004, 0x10010008, and so on.  It won't go to zero until it overflows the capacity of a 32-bit unsigned number, and will have crashed your program well before then.